# In a Jenkins job that runs the Build flow plugin, pass it's BUILD_NUMBER to a child job as a parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've got a Jenkins structure where a main job uses the Build Flow plugin to sequentially run all the jobs of my build and test process.

To one of this jobs I want to pass my BUILD_NUMBER (environment variable) as a parameter, i.e.:

```
build( "Build_Release", param1: $BUILD_NUMBER)
```

This does not work because I don't seem to have access to the environment variables from the Build Flow plugin.

Any clues?

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution:

```
build_number = build.environment.get("BUILD_NUMBER")
build("myJob", param1: build_number)
```

or:

```
build("myJob", param1: build.properties.get("number"))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass build number parameter to the job as follows:

```
b = build( "job1", param1: "foo", param2: "bar" )//Main Job
build( "job2", param1: b.build.number )
```

Comment: I don't want the build number of "job1", I want the build number of the job executing that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can access jenkins buildflow job parameters like this:

```
build("job1", parent_param1: params["param1"])
```